# bluetooth low energy sequential connections

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am programming Nordic devices as BLE peripherals. My smartphone acts as BLE central. I would like to transmit data from my smartphone to all the devices one after the other.

Is it possible to compute the time that the smartphone requires to jump from one connection to the other?

Knowing the BLE throughput and the time needed to jump from one connection to the next one, I could compute the time that the whole process would take. Nothe that I do not want to connect all the devices at the same time but one after the other.

Best regards

Comment: I think you need to specify your requirements a little more.  Are we talking calculating the total time it takes to make a connection, transmit the data, and then disconnect under ideal conditions where no error occurred?  That would be the lower end value and the higher end value would depend on the number of retries, etc.

Comment: Actually, I just want to know the time it takes to disconnect from one device and then to establish a connection to another device (under ideal conditions).
The time to transmit the data depends on the amount of data that I will send and I think I can compute that approximately (as I understand, this depends on the operation type, the connection interval and on number of packets transmitted per connection event.)

Comment: Well, if you make assumptions I'm guessing you can calculate the shortest possible time...  You know you can connect to multiple peripherials at a time, though?  No need to wait for a disconnection before moving to the next connection.  You should probably ask about what you're actually trying to do, though, as this question seems to be skirting what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I did not thought of that. Indeed, I could already connect to the next peripheral before the current connection is over. Doing so, the whole process would be dependent on the BLE throughput and the amount of data to send and not on the connection-disconnection steps.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you use regular HCI connection requests you have to make one at a time (once a connection is established then you can start the next).  Also, different hardware has different limits on connections and throw different errors when you hit that limit (if any error... sometimes it just fails in weird ways).

Comment: Well, I think I will just have to test that and establish my own benchmark. I am using [Evothings](https://evothings.com/doc/) to develop the APP so I will have to check how this can be achieved.